# How to run optimizations in python one iteration at a time?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to run a fairly large amount of optimizations in parallel (N optimizations). The idea is to evaluate the cost-functions "somewhere else" for all optimizations. Therefore I would like to have an array of parametersets (of length N) from all optimisations, send it away, receive a list of costs back (of length N) to generate a new set of parameters or finish the job.

Can this be achieved using the optimizers available in SciPy?

Comment: Are you searching for a way to do parallel processing or how to write multiple optimizations?

Comment: I want to have multiple optimizations all do one iteration so that I can send the new parameters as one job. I don't see how or if I can achive this with the methods provided by SciPy.

Comment: Still a bit inprecise. It sounds also tricky to do this kind of customized optimization inside scipy (e.g. saving the space of something like SLSQP is hmm, hard at least; not that you need this, but this kind of indicates some limitations), but i don't understand enough of your task. There are probably much more evident theoretical issues in your approach, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: So you're basically figuring out how to do a grid search in a parallel fashion? Have you looked into sklearn's [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). It can run a grid search in parallel to find the best parameters for optimizing your cost function.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr The ```all do one iteration``` let's me believe it's not about grid-search (where you would need some wrapper-function to imitate sklearn's api) on complete runs. But i might be wrong.

Comment: @Sascha: correct. I have completely independent optimizations. I could now loop over them or use threads, but actually, there are so many optimizations, that it is worth just going to the GPU. Now implementing the cost function on the GPU is easy (not a complicated case). But I do not want to implement the optimization on the GPU. So I thought a compromise is, to just communicate the parameters and the cost values between the GPU and the SciPy optimizers. However, since communication with the GPU is limited, I want to send the new parameters/cost values always as a single array.

Comment: @MrZ GPU won't help for 99,9% of use-cases (too much details to outline) and we still don't know anything about your exact use-case/data/opt-problems. Also: the function-evaluation is not necessarily the time-dominating part of these algorithms. (But what do we know... There is no mentioning of some chosen alg)